# How to add a hook to save things on kill-ring (or clipboard ring) before a frame is deleted?

Tags: hooks, frames, kill-ring, clipboard, delete-selection-mode

**Context**:

I have been using an interesting software called [Emacs Anywhere](https://github.com/zachcurry/emacs-anywhere). It helps me bring emacs keybindings for stuff like this (editing text for a question on Stack Exchange). Overall, the software has been working well!

This is an illustration of the **expected** behavior:

1. I put my cursor on a text box from Stack Overflow to write a
   question.
2. Then, I invoke Emacs Anywhere with a hotkey
3. Cool, I am editing text now with Emacs
4. After finishing what I want to ask on SO, I press `C-x 5 0`, the
   frame is deleted, and the text written on the Emacs frame is
   inserted on the text box my cursor was pointing to on the browser. Cool! I believe in magic :)

The **main problem** I have is when I change the cursor on the browser before the text is inserted. For instance:

1. I put my cursor on a text box from Stack Overflow to write a
   question.
2. Then, I invoke Emacs Anywhere with a hotkey
3. Cool, I am editing text now with Emacs
4. As I am writing text, I decide to check Wikipedia and official
   documentation to base my answer, I left my pointer in a selected
   text from Wikipedia
5. Now, I am back to the Emacs frame editing my question
6. After finishing what I want to ask on SO, I press `C-x 5 0` and the
   frame is deleted. **Unfortunately**, the test I wrote is **not**
   introduced to text box of SO. Why? Because the cursor on the browser is not on the same page and point of the browser it was when I started the process!

Oh, boy. After written a big question, I wished I had saved it. I am sure `yank-pop` could save me!

Hence, I have the idea: maybe I should write something on my config file to add the content of a frame to the clipboard ring (or kill ring) before a frame is deleted!

**Question**

So, I would like to define a hook so that every time I delete an Emacs frame (default keybinding `C-x 5 0`), the content happens to be added to the kill ring (clipboard ring) before the real deletion happens.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @[Drew's](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/105/drew) and @[Gilles](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/25/gilles-so-stop-being-evil) help on [another question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/73213/why-i-cant-compose-commands-mark-whole-buffer-and-copy-region-as-kill-in-el), I managed to build the code below and add it to my config file:

```lisp
(defun pmd/select-and-kill-frame-before-it-is-deleted ()
  "Add content of frame to the kill ring before frame is deleted.
This helps with a problem that I faced while using the software
called Emacs Anywhere."
  (kill-new (filter-buffer-substring beg end)))

(add-hook 'delete-frame-functions 'pmd/select-and-kill-frame-before-it-is-deleted)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you're looking for this hook: **`delete-frame-functions`**

> **`delete-frame-functions`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> This variable can be risky when used as a file-local variable.
>
> Documentation:
>
> Functions run before deleting a frame.
>
> The functions are run with one arg, the frame to be deleted.
> See `delete-frame`.
>
> Note that functions in this list may be called just before the frame is
> actually deleted, or some time later (or even both when an earlier function
> in `delete-frame-functions` (indirectly) calls `delete-frame'
> recursively).

BTW, you can find this hook also if you look for variables whose names end in `hook`, as `delete-frame-hook` is an alias for `delete-frame-functions`.

See the Elisp manual, node [Hooks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html), for information about "abnormal hooks" such as this one -- they're the hooks whose names end in `-functions` instead of `-hook`.